# Building a column based on a sequential step down

Tags: r

I am trying to do a simple bit of math but can't quite figure it out, Basically I have a the following dataframe-

```
Allo <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0)
```

I am trying to create a code that will recognize where the 1 is and then count back up the column based on the idea of an age Gap

So if `CurAge <- 5` and `RetAge <- 24` the middle rows would be 5 and the first row being the remainder.

The resulting column would be like `Allo1 <- c(3,5,5,5,1,0)`

edit:
Building off of what Colonel Beauvel first had I think the solution has to be along the lines of

```
Allo[1:(match(1, Allo)-1)] = seq((RetAge-CurAge-1),0,-5)
```

but I need the count down by a specific number (5) to the remainder for row 1, so a combination of `rep()` and `seq()`?

Comment: Mmh... I don't think you've clarified your problem enough... For example, can you describe what do you do (in your mind) to get `3,5,5,5,1,0` from the given input ?

Comment: Basically RetAge-CurAge =19, It has to count down by 5 and leave the remainder in Allo row 1. I think I would be fine if the numbers go negative as I could write something else to change the negatives to 0.

Comment: `19 - 5 - 5 - 5` doesn't yield 3 as remainder (but 4)... ? Does perhaps the 1 count, so you're basically starting from  18 ?

Comment: (and BTW, `Allo` is not a data.frame, but just a vector)

Comment: Shouldn't the vector really be `c(0,6,6,6,1,0)`? 18 can be equally distributed across elements `2:4` leaving a zero remainder on the first element.

Comment: The 1 also counts towards the 19

Comment: The basis is 5 year break downs, and then the remainder. equal distributions isn't needed.